# How to make fixed Bottom dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I want to make a bottom dialog which will display a text I provide and I can hide and show it whenever I want. This dialog will be shown in all activities. For example, if the app is not connected to the server right now I will show this bottom dialog saying "No connection" and this dialog will be displayed in any activity which is on the screen. How to make this dialog, I tried to make it in XML but I needed to write its show/hide methods in every activity which is a tedious work.
Here is an image which shows the bottom dialog which I am trying to make.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a custom snackbar. https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action

Comment: What is the lowest API for Snackbar, BTW I am supporting API 19

Comment: its belongs to  com.android.support:design:27.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom dialog box that is easy to show on all activities. A dialog box can be customized as the style in your picture.

Here is an example, `requestFeature()` must be called before adding content, Other settings need to be after `setContentView()`.

```
public class YOUR_DIALOG extends Dialog {
    private String mText;

    public YOUR_DIALOG(Context context, String text) {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Window dialogWindow = getWindow();

        dialogWindow.getAttributes().width = android.widget.ListPopupWindow.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialogWindow.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        dialogWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffff7320));
        dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }

    // Everything else remains the same, as is the case with the normal dialog box.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);

        textview = findViewById(...);
        textview.setText(mText);
    }
}
```

And the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity

```
new YOUR_DIALOG(this,"Dialog").show();
```

[image]

Comment: It will be better if you explain what you are doing here, posting code directly is sometimes hard to understand

Comment: When I used it, it didn't work as I expected, when I touch the screen the dialog disappears, I made the dialog non cancelable it blocks the screen.

Comment: @Akef. Yes, by default. The dialog will disappeared when touched outside of it's window. You can call `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` to disable it, Anytime call `dismiss()` to end the dialog

Comment: @XinLake It won't work for me because I want to change the text and the background color when the connection change.

Comment: @Akef It's easy. You can change the text and the background when the dialog is showing, I used it. _Sorry for my poor english_

Comment: @XinLake how to do it?

Comment: @Akef, Change dialog background color: `the_dialog_object.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(new_backgound_color))`, Change text color: encapsulate a method, `the_textview_in_the_dialog.setTextColor(new_text_color)`